# Cannot solve or Reduce my equation in mathematica. What might i be doing wrong?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve or reduce the following equation for p1, but mathematica apparently is unable to solve it.

[image: equation]

In Mathematica I write the code as:

```
Solve[((B*v2)/(p2*(1 + v2))) + ((B*v2*t)/(f*p2*(1 + v2))) - 
   B[(-v2^2)/(p2*(1 + v2)) + (v1/(p1*(1 + v1)))] + 
   t[(h1^2/(n*f*(1 + v1))) + ((B*v2^2)/(f*p2*(1 + v2)))] == 0, {p1}]

and

Reduce[((B*v2)/(p2*(1 + v2))) + ((B*v2*t)/(f*p2*(1 + v2))) - 
   B[(-v2^2)/(p2*(1 + v2)) + (v1/(p1*(1 + v1)))] + 
   t[(h1^2/(n*f*(1 + v1))) + ((B*v2^2)/(f*p2*(1 + v2)))] == 0, {p1}]
```

But it doesnt work, I get the following result,

[image: result]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Need help!!!

Comment: This question was replaced with a different one, and the answers no longer made sense, therefore it needed to be rolled back.  Different questions should be made as new (separate) posts.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple misuse of the square bracket []. Use simple brackets () for grouping terms and it works.

```
gl = ((B*v2)/(p2*(1 + v2))) + ((B*v2*t)/(f*p2*(1 + v2))) - 
     B ((-v2^2)/(p2*(1 + v2)) + (v1/(p1*(1 + v1)))) + 
     t ((h1^2/(n*f*(1 + v1))) + ((B*v2^2)/(f*p2*(1 + v2)))) == 0

Solve[gl, p1]

(*     {{p1 -> (B f n p2 v1)/(
         h1^2 p2 t + B f n v2 + B n t v2 + B f n v1 v2 + B n t v1 v2)}}     *)
```

Comment: Thankyou Akku14 for answering. But i have edited the question and added different equation, in these i have taken care of the brackets. But still no luck...

Comment: @Jack Don't change the question and make existing answers invalid like this.  You have an entirely different question now.  New questions should be posted separately. BTW I do get an output for both of your equations: `{}`. This means no solution, as written in the documentation.